# Modifying Pyspark source code for debugging

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to modify Pyspark source code in order to simulate a non-deterministic scenario in order to test some configuration change. Specifically I had changes to `rdd.py` to sleep for a while to simulate a worker node getting stalled saving to s3 for example. I am able to observe the effects of my change when I run the code in Pyspark shell but not when I run `spark-submit`. This happens even when I run locally.

I am puzzled as to what the difference is between how Pyspark is called from the shell vs via spark-submit. From what I can see the modified `rdd.py` has been deployed to the location under $SPARK_HOME/python/pyspark.

Does anyone have any insights on this ?
I am running spark-2.1.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PySpark libraries are not distributed with job but loaded from `SPARK_HOME`. This means that:

- Modified code should be distributed to all worker nodes.
- You should make sure that `SPARK_HOME` points to the right installation.

Personally I think that modifying Spark code is completely unnecessary unless you want to change `worker.py`, `daemon.py` or other low level details.

High level behavior can be achieved by running things in `mapPartitions`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I had updated `$SPARK_HOME/python/pyspark/rdd.py` but I didn't update
`$SPARK_HOME/python/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip` which is what I needed to do.